# Avahi listing pi without .local suffix

Tags: ssh, dns

I have a number of raspberry pis that I swap out (only one running at a time). One responds to `ssh pi@raspberrypi` rather than `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` like the rest.

I have looked at how to change this but I can only find information on changing the `raspberrypi` hostname. I don't think this has any influence on the `.local` suffix set by Avahi but I currently cannot test to confirm.

How can I explicitly 'force' Avahi to set the `.local` suffix when using Multicast DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains some errors and mis-interpretation.

`.local` addresses are resolved by mDNS (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address ) by sending to Multicast DNS 224.0.0.251

You can not change anything on the Pi to "fix" this, because it is not the Pi.

The only way I have to "fix" this when there are problems is to restart everything on your local network.

PS Running multiple machines, with the same hostname, just creates confusion - even if not present simultaneously. You should assign a unique hostname to each machine.

Comment: Do you have an idea why the OP can address one RasPi only with `raspberrypi`?

Comment: I admit my knowledge is limited, thank you for the clarification. I also would like to know why `raspberrypi` alone works. My `/etc/hosts` does not contain any entries

Comment: @myol Unfortunately I can not help - all I can do is suggest what I have found. Unfortunately .local is often used inappropriately (Microsoft is an offender) and it may be cached. Others have reported this behaviour on Microsoft systems. If you want to do further tests try swapping SD Cards between Pi.